# Chrome + gmail high network outbound traffic at startup

Tags: google-chrome, networking, gmail

I'm fighting against a strange behavior in our office network.
Every morning when we switch on our computers, our network was overload on outbound traffic.

After several test I found a possible cause.

I noticed that when we start Chrome (and gmail?) there is a high traffic generated from my computer to Google servers (e.g.: 74.125.133.132). Here a resource monitor screenshot:

[image: Resource monitor screenshot of network traffic out]

The network traffic doesn't go down until I stop chrome and I start it again.

No extensions installed and every possible traffic generating feature is disabled.

[image]

Monitoring the network and restart Chrome every morning is quite annoying. Does someone have a similar behavior and a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

On start up chrome checks weather new update or fixes are available or not..

Or you might be having an chrome extension like _toolbar type, these type of extensions causes a lot of traffic..

Go to settings => extensions => and disable unnecessary and unrecognized extensions..

Hope it solve your problem..

Comment: No extensions installed. Moreover traffic is mainly outbound not inbound